# Changing the font for equation numbering

Tags: formatting, equations, numbering

I know that I can change the font for the equation numbers by redefining the `\theequation` command by, say,

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{{\sffamily\arabic{equation}}}
```

I am wondering if there's a better way of doing this. The reason I ask is because if I include the section number to the equation numbers using the following amsmath command

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

then this will nullify the previous redefinition. Of course an obvious solution for this is to just use

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{{\sffamily\thesection.\arabic{equation}}}
```

but I am curious if there's another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your obvious solution is the right way to go. There's certainly no harm in it.

Comment: I agree; I read the amsmath package manual and it seems the "obvious solution" I mentioned is the most basic approach. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change the font of the brackets around the number.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `\pretocmd` command of the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/etoolbox.html) package to insert code at the beginning of `\theequation` (and leave the rest of its definition unchanged).

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\theequation}{\sffamily}{}{}
```

(The code snipped must be placed after using `\numberwithin` and the like.)